# White horizontal lines in lstlisting

Tags: listings, color, backgrounds

I'm having the following problem: I'm using the [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) to render what is supposed to look like  a teminal screenshot. But the background colour is striped. In my other code snippets the background colour is light gray so it is much less noticeable, but it's really ugly on the black background. I've looked at potential solutions online using `\shaded` or `colorbox`, but none have worked because of the `shadowbox` I'm using.

Any input would be much appreciated.

```
\lstset{%
  language=C,                % choose the language of the code
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{white} ,       % the size of the fonts that    are used for the code
  tabsize=2,                      % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  captionpos=b,                   % sets the caption-position to bottom
  breaklines=true,                % sets automatic line breaking
  breakatwhitespace=true,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at    whitespace
  keywordstyle=\color{white},
  commentstyle=\color{white},
  stringstyle=\color{white},
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{midgray},  % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  stepnumber=2,                   % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line 
                              % will be numbered
  numbersep=5pt,                  % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  frame=shadowbox,
  rulesepcolor=\color{darkgray},
  lineskip={-1.5pt}, % single line spacing
  aboveskip=1.5\bigskipamount,
  belowskip=\smallskipamount,
  escapechar={\@},
  showstringspaces=false,
  backgroundcolor=\color{black}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337770/white-horizontal-lines-in-listing?noredirect=1) was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other, otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Problems with the `lstlisting` environment (margin and white line)](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119863/5764)

Answer (score 6):

Use the [tcolorbox](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox&ei=NARKT-6UJ4a3rAfbm8WxDw&usg=AFQjCNHe1SS1gwB9RyWfCmEei7MeLqTmRQ&sig2=8W93YuXMHuYrKspC8iTM3A) package, which uses the listings package, but has better support for effects.

[image]

This is what a MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{colback=black,coltext=green}
This is a \LaTeX\ example which displays the text as source code
and in compiled form.
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

The package has recently been updated to include English documentation, so you might need to update your distribution. The dotted line in the middle can be removed if you don't use the output frame with the `listing only` option.

Comment: Very nice terminal!

Comment: @Werner Thanks! With a bit of patience and JavaScript you might get it to work as one in a pdf:)