# Problems with the lstlisting environment (margin and white line)

Tags: spacing, listings, margins

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},xleftmargin=0.5cm}
\begin{lstlisting}
Test code
\\ a bit of comments
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

which looks like this:
[image]

Now I have two questions:

1. How do I get rid of this white (clearly unintentional) line?
2. How can I add (a bit of) "gray" space inside the code box (*not* white space ala xleftmargin=0.5cm)? The code is right at the edge of the box, which in my opinion looks sloppy and not well-formated.

Basically I want it to look somewhat like this:
[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. That line is just an artifact of the viewer.
2. Declare an invisible `frame` to the left (and to the right) and use the desired value for `framesep`.

An example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=lr,framesep=8pt,framerule=0pt}
\begin{lstlisting}
Test code
\\ a bit of comments
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Using a frame in the four sides:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible, basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    backgroundcolor=\color{light-gray},xleftmargin=0.5cm,frame=tlbr,framesep=4pt,framerule=0pt}
\begin{lstlisting}
Test code
\\ a bit of comments
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To have control over the separation on each side independently, you can use the `mdframed` package to surround `lstlisting` with a frame with the desired specifications:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\definecolor{light-gray}{gray}{0.95}
\lstset{columns=fullflexible,basicstyle=\ttfamily}
\surroundwithmdframed[
  hidealllines=true,
  backgroundcolor=light-gray,
  innerleftmargin=15pt,
  innertopmargin=0pt,
  innerbottommargin=0pt]{lstlisting}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Test code
\\ a bit of comments
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to adjust the top and left margin independently?

Comment: @Tom in this case, a better approach would be to use `mdframed`. Please see my updated answer.