# Problem inserting C snippet

Tags: listings, sourcecode

I am trying to insert an snippet like this
[image]

But when I write

```
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
typedef double real_t; // Esto casi seguro necesita ser tipo doble
real_t UpdatePID(SPid * pid, real_t error, real_t position)
{
.
.
.
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I get this out of margin. Is this a package problem or a problem in my page setup?

[image]

First line of LOG file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6880 64-bit) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2018.11.27) 2 DEC 2018 22:42
entering extended mode
```

**SOLVED:**

I followed this link: [Problems with the lstlisting environment (margin and white line)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119863/problems-with-the-lstlisting-environment-margin-and-white-line)

Answer (score 3):

Just add the option `breaklines=true` to `\lstset` like

```
\lstset{breaklines=true,language=C}
```

I added package `showframe` to visualize the typing area and margins.

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{showframe} % <========= to visualize typing area and margins
\lstset{breaklines=true,language=C} % <=================================


\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
typedef double real_t; // Esto casi seguro necesita ser tipo doble
real_t UpdatePID(SPid * pid, real_t error, real_t position)
{
.
.
.
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

gives you

[image]

Comment: I added breaklines=true but still getting the same. My document class is book, does this affect?

Comment: Yes, I copied your code and I'm getting the same result. Well, my .text file is really long. I can't post the whole code here. But the main issue is just with the C snippet. I added the first line of my log file to my question.

Comment: @XavierPachecoPaulino well, then check your long code, search for definitions for `listings` and copy them  into your code given in your answer. I`m sure you have used some option(s) resulting in your issue you did not show us ...