# LaTeX listing draws weird horizontal lines

Tags: luatex, listings

I use this code to format my code snippets:

```
\definecolor{white}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0.97}     
\definecolor{green}{cmyk}{0.6,0,0.84,0}       
\definecolor{blue}{cmyk}{0.65,0.33,0,0.05}     
\definecolor{rose}{cmyk}{0,0.26,0.38,0}  

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[Sharp]C,
numbers=left,
numberstyle=\color{black},
breaklines=true,
breakatwhitespace=true,
commentstyle=\color{green},
keywordstyle=\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{rose},
basicstyle=\ttfamily\small\color{white},
backgroundcolor=\color{darkgrey}
}
```

And get this:

[image]

As you can see, there are some horizontal lines, but not on every line?
Does anyone know how to get rid of them? I would really like to use a dark code theme...
I use LuaLaTeX as compiler if that is of importance

Comment: Do the lines disappear (or at least change) when you Zoom in?

Comment: Which editor do you use? Does it have an option for this, like syntax highlighting or similar?

Comment: I use OverLeaf. I have just exported it to pdf and then the lines are gone!
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Use `tcblisting` instead of `listings`. See the documentation of [tcolorbox](https://ctan.mirrors.hoobly.com/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf). There are a lot of related answers on TeX.SE.

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159569/4427

Comment: This question has been asked many times: see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/334100/listings-lstlisting-environment-has-white-horizontal-lines) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44918/white-horizontal-lines-in-lstlisting) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/557641/listings-avoid-white-line-glitches-in-background-color) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614517/listings-package-avoid-white-lines-in-between-lines-of-code), etc. `tcblisting` is probably the easiest solution.